# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' when trying to write in csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, python-2.x

I have to convert the followin code written in Python 2 to Python3:

```
with open('C:/path_to_csv_file/fold1_1.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row, timeseq in izip(fold1, fold1_t):
        spamwriter.writerow([unicode(s).encode("utf-8") +'#{}'.format(t) for s, t in izip(row, timeseq)])
```

My Python 3 code is the following:

```
with open('C:/Users/path_to_csv_file/fold1_1.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row, timeseq in zip(fold1, fold1_t): 
        for s, t in zip(row, timeseq):
            bytes_var = s.encode('utf-8') +'#{}'.format(t).encode('utf-8') 
            spamwriter.writerow(bytes_var)
```

fold1 contains:

```
fold1 = ['¢©§','¢©§','¢©§']
```

fold1_t contains:

```
fold1_t =[[0, 15, 173999],[0, 457325, 306],[0, 62954, 432]]
```

When I try to execute the code above I get the following error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

The variable bytes_var is type of bytes so normally it should work.
Have I done something wrong with the conversion from Python2 to Python3 to get that error?
Thank you.

Comment: What line is the exception being thrown on?

Comment: @SpoonMeiser At: spamwriter.writerow(bytes_var)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `csv` module is one of the pieces where the conversion Python2 -> Python3 is not really straightforward. The underlying file is expected to be opened as text and no longer as a binary file, but with empty end of lines.

So I would write:

```
with open('C:/path_to_csv_file/fold1_1.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row, timeseq in izip(fold1, fold1_t):
        spamwriter.writerow([s +'#{}'.format(t) for s, t in izip(row, timeseq)])
```

The current error is caused by the csv module sending a unicode string while the undelying file expected bytes.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to change your `wb` to `w`. Also, in python 3, you can do formatted strings by *directly* passing the expression into the curly braces of the string, so the

```
s.encode('utf-8') +'#{}'.format(t).encode('utf-8')
```

can be

```
f'{s}#{t}'.encode('utf-8')
```

Altogether:

```
import csv

fold1 = ['¢©§','¢©§','¢©§']
fold1_t =[[0, 15, 173999], [0, 457325, 306], [0, 62954, 432]]

with open('C:/path_to_csv_file/fold1_1.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row, timeseq in zip(fold1, fold1_t): 
        for s, t in zip(row, timeseq):
            bytes_var = s.encode('utf-8') + f'#{t}'.encode('utf-8') 
            spamwriter.writerow(bytes_var)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The code gets executed like that, but  'w' isn't different from 'wb' ?

Comment: @C96 What do you mean?

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong but the file would not contain different information if I open it in binary mode with 'wb' instead of 'w' ?

Comment: @C96 Can you show me what the file will contain when you run the python 2 code?

Comment: For example that is the first line of fold1_1 b'\xc2\xa2#0',b'\xc2\xa9#15',b'\xc2\xa7#173999'

Comment: @C96 Please paste the entire csv file into your post.